# Is there an id/number that connects each user to their corresponding resources in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

For example if a user signs in with AWS Cognito User Pools and their name, email etc is stored in Cognito and then once in the app with the API they create a user profile that stores a whole bunch of info using Appsync and DynamoDB - what connects this user's cognito info to their corresponding profile info in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM is the service that controls identities and authorisation on the AWS platform. IAM manages access to AWS services for your developers, scripts and applications etc. IAM defines [unique IDs for users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids).

I think the more relevant thing you are asking about is how a user authenticated by Cognito can be tied to data in DynamoDB. The short answer is to use the Cognito sub (subject). More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

> The sub claim is a unique identifier (UUID) for the authenticated
>   user. It is not the same as the username which may not be unique.

The sub is not natively understood by DynamoDB, you will need to store the sub in your items.

The sub for a Cognito user never changes and is always unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you say it’s common practice then to store the sub as user item in DynamoDB?

Comment: Yes for sure. That's what I do. As an aside, using the sub as a table partition key is essentially the only way of implementing fine grained security in DynamoDB.